# Dynamic Countif when data range is letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have Data range full of letters and want a dynamic count in excel when a filter is applied.

I used following formula for numbers

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET($FW$40:$FW$144, ROW($FW$40:$FW$144)-MIN(ROW($FW$40:$FW$144)),,1)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH(1,$FW$40:$FW$144))+0)`

I thought of changing the last part to look for a text e.g."A" would work but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Can somebody show me a formula on how I can do this when my data is all letters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading I worked out you can use -- to search for text.

My formula works... Thanks

Comment: you can use what? please post the modified formula that worked for you